# Finding derivative given an identity

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I've been working through some past papers for my course as my exam has been cancelled due to pandemic. However, they are not supplying any solutions just the questions.
I'm absolutely stuck on how to solve this question without going through a very long derivative process using the chain rule and product rule.
Is there a simpler way to solve this using the identity?

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3P53.png)

I would go about solving it like this:

[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcXEE.png)

However, get stuck with the simplification there. Is there an easier way using the identity or can I simplify my answer further?

Comment: Please use Mathjax to type the formulas in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done.
$$\begin{align}v'(x)&=\frac{-2x^2+2x}{(x+1)^3}+\frac{2x-1}{(x+1)^2}\\&=\frac{-2x^2+2x}{(x+1)^3}+\frac{2x-1}{(x+1)^2}\frac{x+1}{x+1}\\&=\frac{-2x^2+2x+2x^2-x+2x-1}{(x+1)^3}\\&=\frac{3x-1}{(x+1)^3}\end{align}$$

You could have used the hint as well:
$$\begin{align}v'(x)&=v\frac{d(\ln v)}{dx}\\&=\frac{x(x-1)}{(x+1)^2}\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln x+\ln(x-1)-2\ln(x+1)\right]\\&=\frac{x(x-1)}{(x+1)^2}\left[\frac 1x+\frac1{x-1}-\frac2{x+1}\right]\\&=\frac{x(x-1)}{(x+1)^2}\frac{x^2-1+x^2+x-2x^2+2x}{x(x-1)(x+1)}\\&=\frac{3x-1}{(x+1)^3}\end{align}$$

Comment: So obvious when you put it like that, just couldn't see that I could do that trick. Thanks :)

Comment: I've added the solution using logarithm as well

Comment: Really helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: Please mark it as accepted if it completely answers your question